# Problemas no PUT com Spring data JPA

Tags: java-8, get, spring-data, spring-jpa, postman

Estou usando arquitetura Controller, DTO, Repositoy, Service

Uso Postman para testar as requisições, eu consigo fazer POST no Usuario normalmente e quando faço GET o Postman me retorna

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Arthur",
    "cpf": "281.590.328-89",
    "cnh": "35214349616",
    "telefone": "(61) 99805-2147",
    "email": "reginaandreiaaparicio_@inforgel.com",
    "senha": "1234",
    "perfil": "alugador",
    "endereco": {
        "id": 3,
        "logradouro": "Quadra SHPS Quadra 502",
        "bairro": "Setor Habitacional Pôr do Sol (Ceilândia)",
        "numero": 927,
        "complemento": " ",
        "cidade": "Brasília",
        "estado": "DF"
    }
}
```

Faço POST no Carro passando id do Usuario e o GET me retorna:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "usuarioRegistrador": {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Arthur",
        "cpf": "281.590.328-89",
        "cnh": "35214349616",
        "telefone": "(61) 99805-2147",
        "email": "reginaandreiaaparicio_@inforgel.com",
        "senha": "1234",
        "perfil": "alugador",
        "endereco": {
            "id": 3,
            "logradouro": "Quadra SHPS Quadra 502",
            "bairro": "Setor Habitacional Pôr do Sol (Ceilândia)",
            "numero": 927,
            "complemento": " ",
            "cidade": "Brasília",
            "estado": "DF"
        }
    },
    "kmsRodados": 555.0,
    "documentoCarro": "555",
    "tipoCombustivel": "55",
    "marca": "CAMARO",
    "modelo": "GOL BOLA",
    "placa": "TTT-1555",
    "valorCarro": 363636.0,
    "estaAlugado": true
}
```

Quando faço um POST no Aluguel, passando id do Usuario e id do Carro, o GET me retorna `"carro":null`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "usuarioCliente": {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Arthur",
        "cpf": "281.590.328-89",
        "cnh": "35214349616",
        "telefone": "(61) 99805-2147",
        "email": "reginaandreiaaparicio_@inforgel.com",
        "senha": "1234",
        "perfil": "alugador",
        "endereco": {
            "id": 3,
            "logradouro": "Quadra SHPS Quadra 502",
            "bairro": "Setor Habitacional Pôr do Sol (Ceilândia)",
            "numero": 927,
            "complemento": " ",
            "cidade": "Brasília",
            "estado": "DF"
        }
    },
    "carro": null,
    "retirada": "2009-08-07",
    "entrega": "2019-08-04",
    "valor": 99.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

confira se no DTO, vc esta passando o carro
public static AluguelDto converteEntidadeEmDto(Aluguel aluguel) {
        AluguelDto dto = new AluguelDto();
        dto.setId(aluguel.getId());
        dto.setEntrega(aluguel.getEntrega());
        dto.setCarro(aluguel.getCarro());
        dto.setUsuarioCliente(aluguel.getUsuarioCliente());
        dto.setRetirada(aluguel.getRetirada());
        dto.setValor(aluguel.getValor());
        return dto;
    }

```
public static Aluguel converteDtoEmEntidade(AluguelDto dto) {
    Aluguel aluguel = new Aluguel();
    aluguel.setCarro(dto.getCarro());
    aluguel.setId(dto.getId());
    aluguel.setEntrega(dto.getEntrega());
    aluguel.setRetirada(dto.getRetirada());
    aluguel.setValor(dto.getValor());
    aluguel.setUsuarioCliente(dto.getUsuarioCliente());
    return aluguel;
}
```